# Api Post 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a post API on a dummy node project; it worked fine there, but implemented the same API on the main project I got the 400 Bad request error while running this API on a post.

**Route js**

```
router.post("/add",(req, res) => {
  const planName = req.body.planName;
  const planPrice = req.body.planPrice;
  const planMode = req.body.planMode;
  const planStatus = req.body.planStatus;

  const newAddon = new Addon({
    planName,
    planPrice,
    planMode,
    planStatus,
  });
  console.log("newAddon", newAddon)

  newAddon.save()
    .then(() => res.json("Addon added"))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(400).json("Error in Add Addon route")
    );
});
```

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const addonsSchema = new Schema(
    {
        planId: {type: Number,required: true},
        planName: {type: String,required: true},
        planPrice: {type: Number,required: true},
        planMode: {type: String, required:true},
        planStatus: {type: String, required:true}, //active or inactive
    },
    {timestamps: true},
);

const Addon = mongoose.model("Addons", addonsSchema);
module.exports = Addon
```

**index.js**

```
const addonRouter = require('./routes/addon')
app.use('/addons',addonRouter)
```

**Postman Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide `planId` as well in the payload, since you've defined **required** as `true`.

You've 2 ways to solve this:

1. Set the value of `planId` equal to `_id` field that mongodb creates automatically before inserting. You can do this with a `preSave` hook on the model.

   ```
    addonsSchema.pre("save", (next) => {
        // only triggered when creating new records
        if (this.isNew) {
            this.planId = this._id;
        }
        next();
    });
   ```

   And your type for `planId` should be ObjectId.

   ```
   planId: {type: ObjectId,required: true},
   ```
2. Won't recommend but you can remove required attribute from `planId`.